# How is a string literal equal to char*, and how should I take a string as a parameter

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have seen in several pieces of code a string declared as char*. How does this work, surely it is a pointer to a single char, not an array of chars which makes up a string. If I wished to take string input to a method that would be called like this:

```
theMethod("This is a string literal");
```

What datatype should the parameter be?

Comment: char * will do the work if ur storing string in char in array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> surely it is a pointer to a single char, not an array of chars

It's a pointer to the first character of an array of `char`. One can access each element of the array using a pointer to its first element by performing pointer arithmetic and "array" indexing.

> What datatype should the parameter be?

`const char *`, if you don't wish to modify the characters from within the function (this is the general case), and `char *` if you do.

Comment: The function takes a string to pass to SDL_WM_SetCaption(const char*, const char*) When I tried taking char* myself, the caption that appears in the SDL window is a load of nonsense. (This issue may be SDL specific, but could something be going wrong)

Comment: @handuel Unfortunately, that's not enough context. You should show some actual code. "I tried taking char" is non-informative.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I will accept this answer and start a separate question for this problem, as it is hard to express in 600 characters.

Comment: I've solved the problem, it was just a stupid mistake, however I get this compiler warning: main.cpp:10:41: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings] when I call the function that takes a char* as a parameter. Is this OK, and should I try and fix it.

Comment: @handuel The compiler is right (until you are a beginner, the compiler is **always** right), and you should always fix every warning. This warning tells you that you should treat a string literal as an array of `const char`, since you can't modify its contents. `char *foo = "bar";` is wrong, `const char *foo = "bar";` is good, and ***as I've just explained,*** your function should take `char *` if you are modifying its argument. If you don't, it **should** take `const char *`.

Comment: I'm not modifying it. However I am setting a class variable to it. And if I keep it as const when I try and set the variable I get this: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]. As far as I could work out, the only way of solving this is to take char* with no const.

Comment: @handuel Nah, you make the global variable `const char *` too then. (See, every C programmer manages to maintain const correctness -- you should do so too.)

Comment: You should make your class variable be of type `const char *`.

Comment: @Zack, Oh yeah... I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. Sorry for being dim.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common beginner-C confusion.  A pointer to *any* type, `T *`, is ambiguously *either* a pointer to a single object of type T, or a pointer to an element within a linear array of objects of type T, size unspecified.  You, the programmer, are responsible for knowing which is which, and passing around length information as necessary.  If you get it wrong, the compiler stands by and watches as your program drives off the undefined-behavior cliff.

To the extent C has strings (there is a strong case to be made that it doesn't *really*) they take shameless advantage of this ambiguity, such that when you see `char *` or `const char *` in a C program, it *almost always* will be a pointer to a string, not a single `char`.  The same is not true of pointers to any other type.

Answer (score 0):

per definition is "string" of type char * (or unsigned char * or const char *) however, it is a pointer to the first character of that character chain (i dont want to use the words array or vector). The Difference is to see in char: 'x' (single quote)

this is good old c programming (sometimes i could cry for loosing it)

```
char *p = "i am here";
for (q=p; ++q; *q) { // so lets start with p walk through and end wit the /0 after the last e 
    if (*q=='h') { // lets find the first 'h' and cut the string there
        *(q-1)=0;
        break;
    }
}
```

i used no const and other probs here, i just try to clearify

Comment: In this example, you're modifying a string constant. String constants have type (char *) for historical reasons, but the compiler is allowed to put them in read-only memory (and usually will these days), and you are not allowed to modify them.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: sure! you are right, i just tried to point out what a "string" is and a char *, i think this is a good question for somebody learning C.